# Can one transit through Galeão International Airport, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil without a visa?

Tags: airports, us-citizens, transit-visas, rio-de-janeiro

We bought tickets for two people to fly from Rio de Janeiro, Brazil to Santiago, Chile and then on to other places. This was one purchase. One person (from the USA) cannot get his visa in time. He has just carry-on.

If coming from the USA, can he transfer in Galeão International Airport (GIG) within a few hours, without a visa?

(In that case we only have to buy one new ticket from Los Angeles, USA to Rio.)

Comment: Is this person a US citizen?

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/):

> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Passengers with an onward ticket in transit through Rio de Janeiro Galeao International (GIG).